# How can I rename my Apex Class name in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-chatter

How can i rename my Apex class?

For example if I want to change the name of my apex class from ABC to ABC123, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to do it through a metadata deployment, your only option would be to delete the old class and create a new one.

In the ui (Setup > Develop > Apex Classes), you can change the class name, but it won't change any of the references, so if you don't manually change all references to the class, you might start getting errors that say:

> Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation

Renaming a class in the ui will associate a different name with the same salesforce id for the class, so there is a subtle difference between that and deleting and creating a new class.

Answer (score 0):

***there are 3 ways to rename Apex Classes***

**Using Force.com,**  follow this link
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Miscellaneous
or 
[Force.com IDE didn't reflect my changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455233/force-com-ide-didnt-reflect-my-changes)

**Using mavenmate**
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/61405/how-to-rename-class-in-mavensmate

**Salesforce CLI**
In VS code login using Salesforce CLI and rename the apex class and its reference by find & replace class Name. and 
Rename the class in apex class folder to new name and deploy to org 
after that you can see 2 classes old class and new Class with same content delete the old class